# Group Dataframe rows while deleting specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe with several columns. I want to group rows based on multiple column values.

My source dataframe looks like this:

```
category   code  color    property_value        price
A          xx01  white    128                   $10.00
B          xx01  white    128                   $5.00
A          xx02  black    128                   $10.00
B          xx02  black    128                   $5.00
A          xx03  white    256                   $15.00
B          xx03  white    256                   $25.00
```

The purpose of the grouping is to delete columns `color` and `code` and only use `property_value` while saving `categories`.

target dataframe should look like :

```
category   property_value        price
A          128                   $10.00
B          128                   $5.00
A          256                   $15.00
B          256                   $25.00
```

Any leads on how I can achieve this result using pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more like a drop duplicate operation than a grouping operation:

```
# suppose your DataFrame is df
df = df[['category', 'property_value', 'price']].drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```